# Apache load balancer just uses first entry

Tags: apache, load-balancing, reverse-proxy

I have configured a loadbalancer for Apache as following:

```
<Proxy "balancer://mycluster">
    BalancerMember "http://127.0.0.1:8081/" loadfactor=1
    BalancerMember "http://127.0.0.1:8082/" loadfactor=1

    ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests
</Proxy>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName subdomain.example.com

    ProxyPass / "balancer://mycluster"
    ProxyPassReverse / "balancer://mycluster"
</VirtualHost>
```

If i fire some requests at it like in

```
for i in `seq 1 100`
curl http://subdomain.example.com/ping &
```

I get my `pong` (which is the balancers response) 100 times

But the logs are only showing the requests in my first  BalancerMember at port 8081.

How can I debug this or change to a round-robin style?